# MySQL error: 1064 while importing a database

Tags: mysql, import, export

I have exported a database from MySQL version 5.5.40, but when I am importing it to MySQL 5.5.44 I get an error regarding the syntax.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `key_value` (
  `collection` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'A named collection of key and value pairs.'
`value` longblob NOT NULL COMMENT 'The value.',
  PRIMARY KEY (`collection`,`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COMMENT='Generic key-value storage table. See the state system for…';
```

The error received is:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`value` longblob NOT NULL COMMENT 'The value.',
  PRIMARY KEY (`collection`,`nam' at line 3
```

Please suggest.

Comment: you missed comma ',' before value longblob ...

Answer (score 4):

The solution, per [this comment in the drupal.org issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2496331#comment-10029863), is this:

Change this:

``` CREATE TABLE ``key_value`` (
  ``collection`` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'A named collection of key and value pairs.'
``value`` longblob NOT NULL COMMENT 'The value.',
  PRIMARY KEY (``collection``,``name``)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Generic key-value storage table. See the state system for…' ```

to this:

``` CREATE TABLE ``key_value`` (
  ``collection`` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'A named collection of key and value pairs.',
  ``name`` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The key of the key-value pair. As KEY is a SQL reserved keyword, name was chosen instead.',
  ``value`` longblob NOT NULL COMMENT 'The value.',
  PRIMARY KEY (``collection``,``name``)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Generic key-value storage table. See the state system for'; ```

then remove this near the end to prevent another error:

``` ALTER TABLE ``key_value``
 ADD ``name`` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The key of the key-value pair. As KEY is a SQL reserved keyword, name was chosen instead.'; ```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `name` column in your table but you are creating your primary key with combination of PRIMARY KEY (`collection`,`name`). So just remove name and try.

Also add ',' after collection column and before value column as suggested by Khalid.

Finally you can use -

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `key_value` (
  `collection` VARCHAR(128) CHARACTER SET ASCII NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'A named collection of key and value pairs.',
`value` LONGBLOB NOT NULL COMMENT 'The value.',
  PRIMARY KEY (`collection`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COMMENT='Generic key-value storage table. See the state system for…';
```

Comment: I have exported an existing, to be more precise a Drupal 8,  database and I am not sure how that can be possible.

Comment: may be it was happen during copy from your backup file, you can read your backup .sql file..it should not be...

Comment: Added to my comment, when I open the file in an editor, later to this statement I find alter table command is adding a 'name' field to the same table. 

ALTER TABLE `key_value`
 ADD `name` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The key of the key-value pair. As KEY is a SQL reserved keyword, name was chosen instead.';

Comment: As per my understanding there should not be 2 statements first for create table and 2nd for alter in backup file...as backup will just update create statement of final table and then data insertion statements....finally I think you have got solution so enjoy... :)